# TypeError: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-authentication

I'm building a react app, and I want to integrate google signin using firebase. I've followed the firebase documentation in implementing it, yet I keep getting this error - "TypeError: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor".
Here's my code;

firebase.prod.js

```
import Firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyASOat6CaIWxzwnepoGBHDpltnf9jH1QH0",
  authDomain: "cv-builder-c0429.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://cv-builder-c0429.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "cv-builder-c0429.appspot.com",
};

const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config);

export { firebase };
```

signin.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { FirebaseContext } from "../context/firebase";

export default function SignUp() {
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const googleSignIn = () => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('profile');
      provider.addScope('email');

      firebase.auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
 
  return (
    <button onClick={googleSignIn}>Sign in with google</button>
  )
};
```

Any help in fixing this will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you link us to the spot in the docs where we can find this code?

Comment: You mean the GitHub repo?  https://github.com/Joblyn/Cv-Builder/blob/develop/src/pages/signin.js

Comment: Oh, that could help. But I was talking about the part of the official documentation you say you got this code from.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: On that site, in the code box under *Create an instance of the Google provider object*: if I switch from v8 to v9 it no longer shows you that `new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();` syntax. Are you on v9 perchance? (They write that v9 is designed to be more modular, and maybe as a result they stopped exporting that `GoogleAuthProvider()` default.) Anyway, you should try the v9 syntax there if you haven't yet.