# how can i eliminate this error? TypeError: GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a file where I have all the firebase services for my app

> firebase.js

```
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signOut,
  initializeApp,
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  getDatabase,
} from './firebase-imports.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDOPnedni_lGkXKH8QvH6JV1iTbcAwmJm4',
  authDomain: 'social-network-ac42d.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'social-network-ac42d',
  storageBucket: 'social-network-ac42d.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '301187927033',
  appId: '1:301187927033:web:6bf303b353329946510b28',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const dataBase = getDatabase(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const SignUpUser = (email, password) => createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then(
    (userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      sendEmailVerification(user).then(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
        alert(`Se ha enviado un correo de verificación a ${user.email}`);
      });
    },
  );

export const SignInUser = (email, password) => {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(
      (userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('ingreso exitoso');
      },
    );
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};

export const googleSignWithPopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });

export const saveTask = (title, description) => addDoc(collection(db, 'Posts'), { title, description });

export const userSignOut = () => {
  signOut(auth)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('estas afuera');
      // Sign-out successful.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('hubo un error');
      // An error happened.
    });
  return signOut(auth);
};
```

I want to do a LogIn with Google from firebase. This is shown in the signUp.js file

> signUp.js

```
  import { SignUpUser } from './firebase.js';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-cycle
import { changeView } from './viewController.js';

export default () => {
  const viewSignUp = ` <form class='signUpForm' id='signUpForm'>
  <div class='containerForm'> 
    <figure>
      <img class='Icono' src='images/iPhone 13/Logo.png' alt='Icono'><br>
    </figure>
    <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
    <input type='text' class='nickname' id='nickname' placeholder='nickname'><br>
    <input type='email' class='email' id='email' placeholder='email' required minlength='8'> <br>
    <input type='password' class='password' id='password' placeholder='password'><br>
    <h6>  By clicking Agree & Join, you agree to the  User Agreement, <br>
          Privacy Policy, and Cookie Policy. 
    </h6>
    <input type='submit' class='submitSignUp-' value='Sign Up'>
  </div>
  <footer> Made by Viviana, Camila & Paula</footer>
</form>`;

  const signUpContainer = document.createElement('div');
  signUpContainer.innerHTML = viewSignUp;

  const formSignUp = signUpContainer.querySelector('#signUpForm');
  formSignUp.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    SignUpUser(email, password)
      .then(() => { changeView('#/post'); })
      .catch((error) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
        alert(errorMessage);
      });
  });
  return signUpContainer;
};
```

But when running the unit tests with Jest it shows me the following error:

> TypeError: _firebaseImports.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor

```
  30 | const dataBase = getDatabase(app);
  31 | const auth = getAuth();
> 32 | const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
     |                  ^
  33 |
  34 | export const SignUpUser = (email, password) => createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  35 |   .then(
```

How can I solve that?. Remember that I am using Vanilla JS and and the latest version of Firebase (V9).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - Firebase - GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397381/react-firebase-googleauthprovider-is-not-a-constructor)

Comment: They use an older version of Firebase. Here is the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=es-419

Comment: I see, thanks so much for clarifying—I do see a comment in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151442/typeerror-firebase-auth-googleauthprovider-is-not-a-constructor): "On that site, in the code box under Create an instance of the Google provider object: if I switch from v8 to v9 it no longer shows you that new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); syntax. Are you on v9 perchance? (They write that v9 is designed to be more modular, and maybe as a result they stopped exporting that GoogleAuthProvider() default.) Anyway, you should try the v9 syntax there if you haven't yet."